# Multiple display options in 23.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, 23.04

I was trying to use my android tablet as a second screen using RD client. It was mirrorring my screen, (although its not working well). But I wanted to use it as an extended screen, for which there used to be some options in previous versions, in Settings->Display. But in 23.04 it seems to be absent. Any idea how I can access it?